# angular-cli "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json" analogue @1.5

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I been using "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json" for a while now to compile aot folder for the webpack (multi-app scenario). It seems that ngc.ts file was renamed to "perform_compile" with no obvious way to call it directly.

What is analogue of "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json" at versing 1.5 (5.0.0) ?

Comment: How do you call? npm scripts?

Comment: directly in the bash or via npm run e.g "webpack:prod": "set NODE_ENV=live && ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json && webpack --progress --d"

Comment: Then it should work as it was

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: "$ ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json
bash: ngc: command not found"  and if I run npm run webpack:prod hten aot folder won't be generated.  the ng --version is "Angular CLI: 1.5.0"

Comment: `$ ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json bash: ngc: command not found` means that you haven't installed @angular/compiler-cli globally. But you should not. For `aot folder won't be generated` add your tsconfig-aot.json

Comment: https://github.com/mcgri/NgMultiApp/blob/master/NgMultiApp/tsconfig-aot.json  you could find it there. It's my example project (it wasn't updated to v5 tho)

Comment: `"genDir":` has no effect in angular 5. Use `compilerOptions.outDir` instead. It's typescript option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158508/discussion-between-simeon-grigorovich-and-yurzui).

Comment: https://github.com/alexzuza/angular2-typescript-systemjs/blob/master/tsconfig-aot.json#L4

Comment: looks like it is trying to compile AOT starters before compiling factories. I am getting similar error https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/issues/1582 now... (I removed webpack --progress part from the npm command)

Comment: You should change path to factory For example see https://github.com/alexzuza/angular2-typescript-systemjs/commit/768e49dd0b1de2dadb733f003d5a575e02bd57b8#diff-2c4eac2c2f02e33fe0a107e1f4914897L3

Comment: There is only one idea `import { AppOneModuleNgFactory } from "../../ngModules/AppOneModule.ngfactory";` and `import { AppTwoModuleNgFactory } from "../../ngModules/AppTwoModule.ngfactory";` for second file. In this case ngc should work

Comment: Thanks a lot! you saved me :)